# iOS Auto layout issue when hiding tabBar in new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view hierarchy like this
TabBarController -> NavigationController -> TableViewController

When I tap the button want to push new VC without tabBar, as you can see on the GIF tabBar is hiding properly but the elements on screen aren't placed correctly when VC is pushed and it takes about half a second for it to adjust properly. Why is that?
In my TableViewController I have

```
@IBAction func presentPlayerPressed() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "player", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? PlayerViewController {
        destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```

But I also tried setting `hides bottom bar on push` in Storyboard and it gives the same effect

Also this doesn't change anything

```
    @IBAction func presentPlayerPressed() {
    let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playerVC")
    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just try to add this in second viewdidload

       edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.all
       extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

Comment: There are several ways you can resolve this and you just need to know viewcontroller lifecycle. Use `viewWillAppear` to update the frame.

Comment: None of these work :/